# Automation tool or code for creating apiconnect services

Tags: automation, ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I am trying to create APIs using automation techniques. Need some suggestion on how to achieve it. any specific tool or through javascript or any other coding?

Comment: You can use Google API editor for Creating API's.

Answer (score 1):

You probably wont be able to completely automate creating APIs, but the Loopback project does a really great job of letting you easily create them with a few inputs. Looks like there is a CLI that you could use with whatever automation system you are building: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-cli

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [APIConnect toolkit](https://developer.ibm.com/apiconnect/getting-started/), it helps you create and deploy (etc, etc) apis / products.